# Passing the ID to url string via jquery and then picking it by PHP without page refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, url

I want to pass the ID to the urlstring  via jQuery without refreshing jQuery and `#` tag so that I could get the ID via php `$_get['ID']` function.

But the problem is that

1. If I use `#`, page did not get refreshed, however PHP did pick the ID from url.
2. If I don't use #, then php do picks the ID but Page get refreshed.

I want to pass an id to php without refreshing the page.

```
//javascript
function com(id) {
    location.href = '#?ID=id'; //by this way way,page doesn't refresh, ID appears in the url string but ID is not picked by  PHP as # is there
    // location.href = '?ID=id';   this way way, ID appears in the url string , ID is also  picked by  PHP as # is there.But page get refreshed.
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "getdata.php",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {},
    });
}​
```

```
//php for getdata.php
<?php  echo $_GET['ID'];    ?>
```

Comment: you have to have a page refresh as php is server side. it cannot pick up the changes in the url until its reloaded. however ajax may be a better approach

Answer (score 2):

You need to educate yourself about server-side vs. client-side operations. Javascript is client side. The server (running PHP in your case) knows nothing about what javascript is doing unless you send some information back. This can be accomplished via a page refresh or via ajax (put simplistically).

What you want is ajax which is an asynchronous request that goes back to the server. The server can then handle it and choose to pass information back to the page. Look into jQuery's [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Update based on your updated comment:

```
function com(id) {
    //forget about appending the id. This isn't doing anything.
    //You can use it for informational purposes or so that if someone cuts and pastes
    //the link you can handle it server side appropriately.
    location.href = '#?ID=id';

    //instead focus on this call. append your query string to the url    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getdata.php?ID=12345",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data); //should alert the id processed by php
        },
    });
}​
```

Comment: @AanaSaeed - changing the url without a page refresh does not notify the server of anything. So you need to drop that line of thinking. Instead focus on your ajax call. By calling `url: "getdata.php?ID=12345"` the receiving page, getdata.php can then parse out the id using `$_GET['id']`.